# Is it possible to set ViewPager inside a fragment class?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I have a `Fragment` class and an `Activity` class which is related to that fragment, **ViewPager** has been initialized inside the Activity of `MizActivity`

My question is it possible to move `ViewPager` initialization from Activity class to the Fragment class So that I have better control?

Thanks in advance

***Fragment***

```
@SuppressLint("InflateParams") public class TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment extends Fragment {

    TextClicked mCallback;

    public interface TextClicked{
        void sendText(int position);
    }

    private Activity mContext;
    private TvShowEpisode mEpisode;
    private ImageView mBackdrop, mEpisodePhoto;
    private TextView mTitle, mDescription, mFileSource, mAirDate, mRating, mDirector, mWriter, mGuestStars, mSeasonEpisodeNumber;
    private View mDetailsArea;
    private Picasso mPicasso;
    private Typeface mMediumItalic, mMedium, mCondensedRegular;
    private DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes mDatabaseHelper;
    private long mVideoPlaybackStarted, mVideoPlaybackEnded;
    private boolean mShowFileLocation;
    private Bus mBus;
    private int mToolbarColor = 0;
    private FloatingActionButton mFab;
    private PaletteLoader mPaletteLoader;
    private ObservableScrollView mScrollView;
    private RecyclerView mEpisodesList;
    private String mShowId;
    private ArrayList<TvShowEpisode> mEpisodes = new ArrayList<TvShowEpisode>();
    private static final String SHOW_ID = "showId";

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    public PlanetAdapter.OnItemClickListener listener;
    /**
     * Empty constructor as per the Fragment documentation
     */
    public TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment() {}

    public static TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment newInstance(String showId, int season, int episode) {
        TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment pageFragment = new TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("showId", showId);
        bundle.putInt("season", season);
        bundle.putInt("episode", episode);
        pageFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return pageFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setRetainInstance(true);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        mContext = getActivity();

        mBus = MizuuApplication.getBus();

        mShowFileLocation = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity()).getBoolean(SHOW_FILE_LOCATION, true);

        mPicasso = MizuuApplication.getPicassoDetailsView(getActivity());

        mMediumItalic = TypefaceUtils.getRobotoMediumItalic(mContext);
        mMedium = TypefaceUtils.getRobotoMedium(mContext);
        mCondensedRegular = TypefaceUtils.getRobotoCondensedRegular(mContext);

        mDatabaseHelper = MizuuApplication.getTvEpisodeDbAdapter();

        // initializing mEpisodes
        mShowId = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString(SHOW_ID);

        Cursor cursor = mDatabaseHelper.getEpisodes(mShowId);
        try {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                mEpisodes.add(new TvShowEpisode(mContext, mShowId,
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_TITLE)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_PLOT)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_SEASON)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_AIRDATE)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_DIRECTOR)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_WRITER)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_GUESTSTARS)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_RATING)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_HAS_WATCHED)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_FAVOURITE))
                ));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }     // mEpisodes initialized


        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(LocalBroadcastUtils.UPDATE_TV_SHOW_EPISODE_DETAILS_OVERVIEW));

        loadEpisode();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            loadEpisode();
            loadData();
        }
    };

    private void loadEpisode() {
        if (!getArguments().getString("showId").isEmpty() && getArguments().getInt("season") >= 0 && getArguments().getInt("episode") >= 0) {
            Cursor cursor = mDatabaseHelper.getEpisode(getArguments().getString("showId"), getArguments().getInt("season"), getArguments().getInt("episode"));

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                mEpisode = new TvShowEpisode(getActivity(),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_SHOW_ID)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_TITLE)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_PLOT)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_SEASON)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_AIRDATE)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_DIRECTOR)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_WRITER)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_GUESTSTARS)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_RATING)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_HAS_WATCHED)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_FAVOURITE))
                );

                mEpisode.setFilepaths(MizuuApplication.getTvShowEpisodeMappingsDbAdapter().getFilepathsForEpisode(
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_SHOW_ID)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_SEASON)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE))
                ));
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.episode_details, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            mCallback = (TextClicked) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement TextClicked");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mBackdrop = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageBackground);
        mEpisodePhoto = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.episodePhoto);
        mDetailsArea = view.findViewById(R.id.details_area);

        mTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.movieTitle);
        mSeasonEpisodeNumber = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        mDescription = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        mFileSource = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        mAirDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textReleaseDate);
        mRating = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView12);
        mDirector = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.director);
        mWriter = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.writer);
        mGuestStars = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.guest_stars);
        mScrollView = (ObservableScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.observableScrollView);
        mFab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab);



        // setting RecyclerView
        mEpisodesList = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.episodesLIST);


        // getting episodeslist
        ArrayList<PlanetModel> episodeslist = new ArrayList<>();

        for(TvShowEpisode e : mEpisodes){
            episodeslist.add(new PlanetModel(e.mEpisode));
        }


        // Setting LinearLayoutManager
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
                = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext.getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        //mEpisodesList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext));
        mEpisodesList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


        // Setting RecyclerView Adapter
        mEpisodesList.setAdapter(new PlanetAdapter(episodeslist, new PlanetAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override public void onItemClick(String item) {
                SharedPreferences getPref = getActivity ().getSharedPreferences("PlanetAdapter", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                int pos = getPref.getInt("newPosition",0);
                mCallback.sendText(pos);
            }
        }));


        mFab.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ViewUtils.animateFabJump(v, new SimpleAnimatorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        play();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        if (MizLib.isTablet(mContext))
            mFab.setType(FloatingActionButton.TYPE_NORMAL);

        final int height = MizLib.getActionBarAndStatusBarHeight(getActivity());

        mScrollView = (ObservableScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.observableScrollView);
        mScrollView.setOnScrollChangedListener(new OnScrollChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChanged(ScrollView who, int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
                final int headerHeight = mEpisodePhoto.getHeight() - height;
                final float ratio = (float) Math.min(Math.max(t, 0), headerHeight) / headerHeight;
                final int newAlpha = (int) (ratio * 255);

                mBus.post(new BusToolbarColorObject(mToolbarColor, newAlpha));

                if (MizLib.isPortrait(mContext)) {
                    // Such parallax, much wow
                    mEpisodePhoto.setPadding(0, (int) (t / 1.5), 0, 0);
                }
            }
        });
        mScrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                ViewUtils.setLayoutParamsForDetailsEmptyView(mContext, view,
                        mBackdrop, mScrollView, this);
            }
        });

        loadData();

        mPicasso.load(mEpisode.getEpisodePhoto()).placeholder(R.drawable.bg).config(MizuuApplication.getBitmapConfig()).into(mEpisodePhoto, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onError() {
                if (!isAdded())
                    return;
                int width = getActivity().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.episode_details_background_overlay_width);
                int height = getActivity().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.episode_details_background_overlay_height);
                mPicasso.load(mEpisode.getTvShowBackdrop()).placeholder(R.drawable.bg).error(R.drawable.nobackdrop).resize(width, height).config(MizuuApplication.getBitmapConfig()).into(mEpisodePhoto);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                if (mPaletteLoader == null) {
                    mPaletteLoader = new PaletteLoader(mPicasso, Uri.fromFile(mEpisode.getEpisodePhoto()), new PaletteLoader.OnPaletteLoadedCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPaletteLoaded(int swatchColor) {
                            mToolbarColor = swatchColor;
                        }
                    });

                    mPaletteLoader.addView(mDetailsArea);
                    mPaletteLoader.setFab(mFab);

                    mPaletteLoader.execute();
                } else {
                    // Clear old views after configuration change
                    mPaletteLoader.clearViews();

                    // Add views after configuration change
                    mPaletteLoader.addView(mDetailsArea);
                    mPaletteLoader.setFab(mFab);

                    // Re-color the views
                    mPaletteLoader.colorViews();
                }
            }
        });

        if (!MizLib.isPortrait(getActivity()))
            mPicasso.load(mEpisode.getEpisodePhoto()).placeholder(R.drawable.bg).error(R.drawable.bg).transform(new BlurTransformation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), mEpisode.getEpisodePhoto().getAbsolutePath() + "-blur", 4)).into(mBackdrop, new Callback() {
                @Override public void onError() {
                    if (!isAdded())
                        return;

                    mPicasso.load(mEpisode.getTvShowBackdrop()).placeholder(R.drawable.bg).error(R.drawable.nobackdrop).transform(new BlurTransformation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), mEpisode.getTvShowBackdrop().getAbsolutePath() + "-blur", 4)).into(mBackdrop, new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onError() {}

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                            if (!isAdded())
                                return;
                            mBackdrop.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#aa181818"), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER);
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    if (!isAdded())
                        return;
                    mBackdrop.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#aa181818"), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER);
                }
            });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        mCallback = null; // => avoid leaking, thanks @Deepscorn
        super.onDetach();
    }

    private void loadData() {
        // Set the episode title
        mTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mTitle.setText(mEpisode.getTitle());
        mTitle.setTypeface(mCondensedRegular);

        mDescription.setTypeface(mCondensedRegular);
        mFileSource.setTypeface(mCondensedRegular);
        mDirector.setTypeface(mCondensedRegular);
        mWriter.setTypeface(mCondensedRegular);
        mGuestStars.setTypeface(mCondensedRegular);

        mAirDate.setTypeface(mMedium);
        mRating.setTypeface(mMedium);
        mSeasonEpisodeNumber.setTypeface(mMediumItalic);
        mSeasonEpisodeNumber.setText(getString(R.string.showSeason) + " " + mEpisode.getSeason() + ", " + getString(R.string.showEpisode) + " " + mEpisode.getEpisode());

        // Set the movie plot
        if (!MizLib.isPortrait(getActivity())) {
            mDescription.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selectable_background);
            mDescription.setMaxLines(getActivity().getResources().getInteger(R.integer.episode_details_max_lines));
            mDescription.setTag(true); // true = collapsed
            mDescription.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (((Boolean) mDescription.getTag())) {
                        mDescription.setMaxLines(1000);
                        mDescription.setTag(false);
                    } else {
                        mDescription.setMaxLines(getActivity().getResources().getInteger(R.integer.episode_details_max_lines));
                        mDescription.setTag(true);
                    }
                }
            });
            mDescription.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
            mDescription.setFocusable(true);
        } else {
            if (MizLib.isTablet(getActivity()))
                mDescription.setLineSpacing(0, 1.15f);
        }
        mDescription.setText(mEpisode.getDescription());

        if (mShowFileLocation) {
            mFileSource.setText(mEpisode.getAllFilepaths());
        } else {
            mFileSource.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        // Set the episode air date
        mAirDate.setText(MizLib.getPrettyDatePrecise(getActivity(), mEpisode.getReleasedate()));

        // Set the movie rating
        if (!mEpisode.getRating().equals("0.0")) {
            try {
                int rating = (int) (Double.parseDouble(mEpisode.getRating()) * 10);
                mRating.setText(Html.fromHtml(rating + "<small> %</small>"));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                mRating.setText(mEpisode.getRating());
            }
        } else {
            mRating.setText(R.string.stringNA);
        }

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mEpisode.getDirector()) || mEpisode.getDirector().equals(getString(R.string.stringNA))) {
            mDirector.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            mDirector.setText(mEpisode.getDirector());
        }

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mEpisode.getWriter()) || mEpisode.getWriter().equals(getString(R.string.stringNA))) {
            mWriter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            mWriter.setText(mEpisode.getWriter());
        }

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mEpisode.getGuestStars()) || mEpisode.getGuestStars().equals(getString(R.string.stringNA))) {
            mGuestStars.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            mGuestStars.setText(mEpisode.getGuestStars());
        }
    }

    Rest   of the  code
}
```

***Activity***

```
public class TvShowEpisodeDetails extends MizActivity implements TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment.TextClicked{

    private static final String SHOW_ID = "showId";

    private ArrayList<TvShowEpisode> mEpisodes = new ArrayList<TvShowEpisode>();
    private int mSeason, mEpisode;
    private String mShowId, mShowTitle;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes mDatabaseHelper;
    private Bus mBus;

    @Override
    protected int getLayoutResource() {
        return R.layout.viewpager_with_toolbar_overlay;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mBus = MizuuApplication.getBus();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set theme
        setTheme(R.style.Mizuu_Theme_NoBackground);

        ViewUtils.setupWindowFlagsForStatusbarOverlay(getWindow(), true);

        ViewUtils.setProperToolbarSize(this, mToolbar);

        mShowId = getIntent().getExtras().getString(SHOW_ID);
        mSeason = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("season");
        mEpisode = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("episode");

        mDatabaseHelper = MizuuApplication.getTvEpisodeDbAdapter();

        Cursor cursor = mDatabaseHelper.getEpisodes(mShowId);
        try {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                mEpisodes.add(new TvShowEpisode(this, mShowId,
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_TITLE)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_PLOT)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_SEASON)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_AIRDATE)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_DIRECTOR)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_WRITER)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_GUESTSTARS)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_RATING)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_HAS_WATCHED)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_FAVOURITE))
                        ));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }


        final ArrayList<PlanetModel> episodeslist = new ArrayList<>();

        for(TvShowEpisode e : mEpisodes){
            episodeslist.add(new PlanetModel(e.mEpisode));
        }

        mShowTitle = MizuuApplication.getTvDbAdapter().getShowTitle(mShowId);
        setTitle(mShowTitle);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.awesomepager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new TvShowEpisodeDetailsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                for (int i=0; i<episodeslist.size(); i++)
                {
                    episodeslist.get(i).setPlanetSelected(false);
                }
                episodeslist.get(position).setPlanetSelected(true);
                //notify your recycler views adaper
                ViewUtils.updateToolbarBackground(TvShowEpisodeDetails.this, mToolbar, 0, mEpisodes.get(position).getTitle(), Color.TRANSPARENT);
            }
        });

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(savedInstanceState.getInt("tab", 0));
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < mEpisodes.size(); i++) {
                if (mEpisodes.get(i).getSeason().equals(MizLib.addIndexZero(mSeason)) && mEpisodes.get(i).getEpisode().equals(MizLib.addIndexZero(mEpisode))) {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                    SharedPreferences setPref = this.getSharedPreferences("TvShowEpisodeDetails", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    setPref.edit().putInt("i", i).apply();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onScrollChanged(TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment.BusToolbarColorObject object) {
        ViewUtils.updateToolbarBackground(this, mToolbar, object.getAlpha(),
                mEpisodes.get(mViewPager.getCurrentItem()).getTitle(), object.getToolbarColor());
    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        mBus.register(this);
        ViewUtils.updateToolbarBackground(this, mToolbar, 0, mShowTitle, Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        mBus.unregister(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("tab", mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
    }


    @Override
    public void sendText(int position) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position,false);
        //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Item Clicked " + text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    private class TvShowEpisodeDetailsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public TvShowEpisodeDetailsAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override  
        public Fragment getItem(int index) {
            return TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment.newInstance(mShowId, Integer.parseInt(mEpisodes.get(index).getSeason()), Integer.parseInt(mEpisodes.get(index).getEpisode()));
        }  

        @Override  
        public int getCount() {  
            return mEpisodes.size();
        }
    }
    
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a `Viewpager` can be setup in a Fragment.

You just need to get the right `FragmentManager` when constructing it i.e use `getChildFragmentManager()` in `mViewPager.setAdapter(new TvShowEpisodeDetailsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));`

From https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/fragmentmanager

> Access the FragmentManager
>
> Accessing in an activity
>
> Every FragmentActivity and subclasses thereof, such as
> AppCompatActivity, have access to the FragmentManager through the
> getSupportFragmentManager() method.
>
> Accessing in a Fragment
>
> Fragments are also capable of hosting one or more child fragments.
> Inside a fragment, you can get a reference to the FragmentManager that
> manages the fragment's children through getChildFragmentManager().